# MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Having a simple Spring Cloud Stream setup.

#### The interface

```
public interface MyKafkaBinding {

    @Output(PUBLISHER)
    MessageChannel publisher();

    @Input("subscriber")
    SubscribableChannel subscriber();
}
```

#### Binding

```
@EnableBinding(MyKafkaBinding.class)
```

#### Listener

```
@StreamListener(MyKafkaBinding.PUBLISHER)
public void listen(MyEvent message) {
    // handle
}
```

#### App properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher.destination=my-kafka-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher.producer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher.content-type=application/json

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.destination=my-kafka-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.content-type=application/json
```

It all works fine. Messages sent using the publisher are received.
Now I'm trying to send a message to this topic from another app, using KafkaTemplate:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message)
```

This time an error is thrown on the receiving side:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'MyApp.subscriber'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.bax.so.MyEvent@6da11fec, headers={b3=[B@304c5b9f, kafka_offset=10, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@742c6888, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=my-kafka-topic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1578085559878, kafka_groupId=my-default-group-id}]
   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
   at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
   at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
   at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:369)
   at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:74)
   at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:431)
   at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:402)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
   at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
   at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1592)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1575)
   at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1534)
   ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
   at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
   at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
   ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Spring version 5+.
Is this a valid scenario at all, sending messages using KafkaTemplate and expect them to be received by a cloud stream subscriber ?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid scenario; something is preventing the binding from being wired up properly. You need to show the binding properties for the subscriber as well. It's best to show all your code and configuration instead of just snippets.

Comment: @GaryRussell Added 2 additional properties. Don't know what else might help.

Comment: You need `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.destination=...` and `...consumer...` properties. By default it will be bound to a topic called `subscriber` so the missing properties, per se, are not the problem.

Comment: @GaryRussell Added subscriber props as well. As pointed in the question, messages sent using the publisher are successfully delivered to the subscriber.

Comment: You are subscribing to the wrong channel - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@StreamListener` is bound to the publisher channel instead of the subscriber channel.

Here is a working example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(MyKafkaBinding.class)
public class So59585815Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59585815Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel publisher;

    @StreamListener("subscriber")
    public void listen(String in) {
        publisher.send(new GenericMessage<>(in.toUpperCase()));
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("subscriber-topic", "foo".getBytes());
        };
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "listener", topics = "publisher-topic")
    public void listen(byte[] in) {
        System.out.println(new String(in));
    }

}

interface MyKafkaBinding {

    @Output("publisher")
    MessageChannel publisher();

    @Input("subscriber")
    SubscribableChannel subscriber();

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher.destination=publisher-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.destination=subscriber-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.subscriber.group=myGroup

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem in my project:

my project cannot connect to Kafka